# Setting the high bit of an integer type of unknown length

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a portable and elegant way to set the high bit of a pointer type in a situation where we don't know if the pointer will have 32, or 64 bits.

I'm working on some legacy code that we inherited from a defunct company. It used to work in a 32 bit environment and now we need a working 64 bit version too. That means much larger pointers than before, and larger magic numbers to represent invalid values. Currently the best proposal will look broadly like this:

```
#if ENVIRONMENT_IS_32_BIT
#define INVALID_PTR_CODE 0x80000000
#else
#define INVALID_PTR_CODE 0x8000000000000000
#endif
```

As I say, I am hoping for something more elegant, and something that will work across different compilers (MSVC, gcc, clang at least). A perfect solution would work for any environment / size of pointer.

Comment: `1 << sizeof(void*)` ?

Comment: @GradyPlayer sizeof is in bytes, not bits

Comment: I think you mean(0x80 << (sizeof(void*) -1))

Comment: lol @Slava ... I actually know that :) `(1 << (sizeof(void*)*8)-1)`

Comment: the point is - "the key is sizeof(void*), you work out the exact shift and what to shift"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static_cast<uintptr_t>(1) << (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(void*) - 1)
```

would do it.

(Note that the current crop of Intel chips has 48 bit pointers under the hood.)

Comment: I think you need to subtract 1 from the shift count to avoid the bit moving outside the valid range.

Comment: Are you sure that unsigned long long is right for a pointer type? I don't want to introduce too many bits on an obscure platform (and we work with a few)

Comment: @TimRandall: Fixed for a stricter pointer type. I'm also happy with the portability now.

Comment: Couldn't uintptr_t be too big for a pointer, for example, on a platform with 24 bit address pointers and 32 bit int?  (This makes more sense if it appeared after Tim's comment that follows.)

Comment: Would it make sense to use sizeof(uintptr_t) also? I prefer not to use two types

Comment: @Eljay: In a sense, C++ compilers already do that. Intel x64 has 48 bit pointers, but every compiler I've come across uses 64 bit pointers.

Comment: @TimRandall: I prefer it my way since the `uintptr_t` is supposed to be the type you ought to use to store the integer equivalent of a pointer, but it *could* be larger. Perhaps `sizeof(void*)` might be 6 but an 8 bit type used for `uintptr_t`?

Comment: @Bathsheba • depends on how the CPU treats those extra 16 bits.  If they are ignored (like on the 24 bit pointer CPU I used back in the day), versus if they are honored (and probably trip a bus address error of some sort).  And if the OP wants the highest valid address high bit (which will required /a priori/ knowledge of the platform characteristics, I think... 24 bit pointers, 48 bit pointers), versus backing store size (32 bit, 64 bit on the architectures respectively).

Answer (score 3):

To get the size of a pointer in bytes you can use `sizeof(void *)`, in bits that's `sizeof(void *) * CHAR_BIT`.  Now you need to get a 1 in that position (keep in mind it's 0 based) so you would do `1ULL << (sizeof(void *) * CHAR_BIT - 1)`.  Then just OR that with your number.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code:

```
int *x = (int*)-1;                           //You set all the bits of `x`
int *y = (int*)((unsigned long long)x >> 1); //y has all bits set besides the msb
x = (int*)(x - y);                           //subtract y from x to have only th msb set
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not portable

Comment: `(long)x` probably should be `(unsigned long long)x`.